# How to map two unidirectional relationships between two domains correctly?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes where i want a *unidirectional* relationship from each to the other:

```
class User {
    HistoryEntry lastFooEntry

    static constraints = {
        lastFooEntry(nullable: true)
    }
}
class HistoryEntry {
    String name
    User createdBy
}
```

According to the [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne) (as i understand it) this is the way to do it. Specifying `belongsTo` would create a bidirectional relationship (what i don't want) and `hasOne` only works with bidirectional relationships anyway.

The problem with the above modelling is, that the following code only works when `entryName=='foo'`. For any other value the assertion is false:

```
def addHistoryEntry(Long id, String entryName) {
    def user = User.get(id)
    if(!user) {
        user = new User(id: id).save()
    }
    def entry = new HistoryEntry(createdBy: user, name: entryName).save()
    if(entryName=='foo') {
        user.lastFooEntry = entry
        user.save()
    } else {
        assert user.lastFooEntry!=entry
    }
}
```

I can work around this by specifying

```
static mappedBy = [createdBy:'']
```

in `HistoryEntry`. But according to IntelliJ IDEA and the [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany) this should only be used in conjunction with `hasMany` and I've never seen it with an *empty* string.

So the question: What is the right way to do this? Or is it a undocumented feature / bug and my workaround is fine so far?

Comment: I don't really understand the 'foo' part, what's supposed to mean `if(entryName=='foo')`? Btw unidirectional realtionships are made without `hasMany`, `hasOne` or `belongsTo`, but in your code you seem to be doing a bidirectional relationship

Comment: Yes, unidirectional relationships are made without `belongsTo` and such. That is why i did not use them. I have two unidirectional relationships, but grails seems to assume a bidirectional one even without me specifying it.

As for the `if(entryName=='foo')`: This is just a demo of the problem. I just want to save a reference to some of the HistoryEntries at the User. For the example these are the last ones that got the name 'foo'.

Comment: User has HistoryEntry, and HistoryEntry has User, Grails assumes a bidirectional relationship because that IS bidirectional, and your example only affirms it: `entry(createdBy user)`, `user.lastFooEntry = entry`

Comment: Sorry, but no. Two unidirectional relationships between two entities are not the same as one bidirectional relationship between them.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between two unidirectional relationships and one bidirectional relationship? Just because it's a single relationship it doesn't mean it's got to be 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a field on the other side of relationship, relationship will remain unidirectional in terms of JVM - i.e. your example is suffficient and you need nothing more. `hasOne` in `User` or/and `belongsTo` in `HistoryEntry` will also work.

The example is probably missing something, because the assertion cannot be false: the `entry` was just created, and never assigned to anything, so it's impossible for that `User` or any other object to reference it. Moreover, `entry` is not saved or flushed yet.

Whether a 1:1 relationship in relational database is 1-directional or 2-directional is more a question of interpretation: normally you only have foreign key only on one end, but the other way can also be calculated.

So don't worry, Grails will never auto-add a reference field on ther other end of a relationship unless you declare that field explicitly.

Comment: Just run the code and you will see it fails at the assertion if `entryName=='foo'`. At least for grails 2.1.1 it does.

Comment: Sorry, it passed for me on Grails 2.1.0. Your example is probably missing something - `id` mapping, `beforeInsert`, or whatever. I believe that if you give it another look, it will become obvious to you too.

Comment: Strange. When i run `addHistoryEntry(1, 'foo')` and then `addHistoryEntry(1, 'bar')` with a fresh grails 2.1.0 project (JDK 1.6) i run into the assertion: `assert user.lastFooEntry!=entry`. The _only_ thing i added to the code in the question is putting the addHistoryEntry method in an otherwise empty controller. I mean the code without the mappedBy, of course, because that is my point.

Comment: How does `lastFooEntry` get assigned at all? `addHistoryEntry()` is a synthetic Grails' method that doesn't know about other fields. Did you use full source of your current classes? Can you quote it in this case? Or, maybe, there exists a `getLastFooEntry()` method?

Comment: No, `addHistoryEntry` is not a synthetic grails method. I used it as a controller action. And the behind-the-scenes assignment of `lastFooEntry` is exactly the point. The code above is the full source code. Today i even checked again with a freshly created grails project where i only used copy&paste with the code in the question (apart from putting `addHistoryEntry` in a controller to have an easy way to call it from a browser).